# Can we use RedirectTo() functions to call the contentblock in marketing cloud

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ssjs, marketingcloudapi

We have a requirement - when we click on a button, it should redirect to particular contentblock. I have tried multiple ways like
`<a href="%%=ContentBlockByKey(@contentBlockKey)=%%">click here</a>`
`<a href="RedirectTo(%%=ContentBlockByKey(@contentBlockKey)=%%)">click here</a>.`

But no luck.
This block contains the unsubscribe page. I believe the cloud page will be the right option. However, I would like to explore this contentblock approach as well

Comment: You can’t link to a content block like this, since it doesn’t have its own url. I would recommend utilising the RedirectTo function along with CloudPagesUrl, to pass your subscriber attributes to your unsubscribe page

Answer (score -1):

In your content block that you are setting your Unsubscribe page you can set variables in two ways:

SET @unsubscribeURLOption = https://example.com/unsubscribe/ (if you don't need to pass any SFMC email values to the cloud page.) Preferred would be:
SET @unsubscribeURLOption2 = CloudPagesURL(#)

In your email content call the contentblockbykey (or ID) at the top of the block that has the link: %%[ contentBlockByKey("contentblockname") ]%%

Your href then calls the value: href="%%=reDirectTo(@unsubscribeURLOption)=%%"